# Custom UIView constraints not being applied

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I have the following custom UIView:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

// container view
lazy var contView: UIView = {
    let cv = UIView()

    cv.backgroundColor = .gray      
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.layer.cornerRadius = 5     
    cv.layer.masksToBounds = true  
    cv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return cv
}()

lazy var t: UIImageView = {
    let tt = UIImageView()

    tt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tt.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    tt.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill      

    tt.alpha = 0

    return tt
}()

let img: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()

    image.backgroundColor = .yellow       
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill        

    return image
}()

let ny: UITextView = {
    let info = UITextView()

    info.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    info.backgroundColor = .blue
    info.text = "Some, Text"        
    info.textColor = .white

    return info
}()

func setupContView() {

    contView.addSubview(img)
    contView.addSubview(ny)
    img.addSubview(t)

    // UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints error
    contView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    contView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
    contView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


    t.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    t.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    img.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    img.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    ny.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    ny.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    ny.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    ny.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(contView)

    setupContView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

When I try to create a reference to this `CustomView` object in my view controller like so...

```
var myCustomView = CustomView()
```

... None of the constraints are applied, and nothing appears. When I try to add constraints in the view controller or `CustomView` to center `myCustomView` I get `UnsatisfiableConstraints` errors. They appear when I add color to them and stuff in the view controller but I already did that in the custom UIView class so its redundant and overrides what I did.

What do I do? I want to be able to create objects of my custom class and have them all look the same, but none of the constraints or custom views I create in my `CustomView` class seem to be doing anything.

Comment: I think you need to give `height` and `width` constraints to `t` as well and you also need to set constraints for `contView` and I dont think you need `cv.layoutIfNeeded()` in your declaration of `contView`

Comment: Doing so gives me `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` as I said

Comment: doing so what? please explain. I gave three suggestions , which have you tried

Comment: I deleted `cv.layoutIfNeeded()` and added `cardView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true` which gives an error

Comment: please apply other suggestions and then I think your code will work, apply constraints for `t` and `contView`

Comment: Wouldn't I just need constraints for the container view? Then the subviews will all have a reference point; it would be relative to wherever I decide to constrain the container view. I have tried all manner of constraints on all subviews and superviews to no avail. I thought my issue would be in `self.widthAnchor` because I usually do `view.widthAnchor` but cannot since there is no view to constrain to since it is not a ViewController

Comment: I think you are not seeing anything because your `contView` currently has no frame, since everything is inside `contView` , applying constraints will give the frame to this view, so I think you should apply constraints to `contView`

Comment: Adding width, height, x, and y constraints to `contView` in my `setupContView` function gives me `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` errors

Comment: Have you commented `cv.layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: Yes I deleted that line

Comment: please show the updated code that you have tried

Comment: you are using ios9 or later? please add `let` instead of `lazy var` , you dont need that

Comment: I did that, still the same problems unfortunately